# Change values based on another column pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I got the following dataframe:

| Contact | Gender | Title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | M |  |
| 2 | F | Dear Ms |
| 3 | Female | Dear Ms |
| 4 | F. | Dear Ms |
| 5 | M |  |
| 6 | M |  |
| 7 | M. | Dear Mr |

How can I change contact 2,3,4 and 7 based on the Title column.

Ms is F and Mr is M

The other contacts who don't have a Title, must nothing happen to it. It must be the same.

So i want this:

| Contact | Gender | Title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | M |  |
| 2 | F | Dear Ms |
| 3 | F | Dear Ms |
| 4 | F | Dear Ms |
| 5 | M |  |
| 6 | M |  |
| 7 | M | Dear Mr |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well In your sample dataframe Gender is correct according to Title:

If that's the case then you can simply do:

```
df['Gender']=df['Gender'].str[0]
```

IF that is not the case then use `np.select()`:

```
#import numpy as np

conditions = [
    df["Title"].str.contains("Ms",case=False).fillna(False),
    df["Title"].str.contains("Mr",case=False).fillna(False)
]
choices = ["F", "M"]

df["Gender"] =pd.Series(np.select(conditions, choices)).replace('0',np.nan).fillna(df['Gender'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
df.loc[df.Title.str.contains('Mr'), 'Gender']='M'
df.loc[df.Title.str.contains('Ms'), 'Gender']='F'
```